# Capture moue movements on a WPF window drawn behind icons and dispose the handler on exit

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, handle, mouselistener

I have a WPF window which I managed to draw behind desktop icons using the tutorial from here: [Codeproject link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/856020/Draw-Behind-Desktop-Icons-in-Windows).

Now I need two things.

First, because of the window position it doesn't capture any moue events which is good for my project. But I only need to make the window capture mouse movements, nothing else. In the tutorial I used it says to use `WH_MOUSE_LL` event. Please if anyone can show any light on this subject.

Secondly, after the window close event there is a static image of the window still showing on the background. May be this is because of the `WorkerW` handle which I produced through the previous code still there. How to dispose that in `Window_closing` event?

Comment: The article specifically mentioned you need to reset the wallpaper and the first comment contains a link to a tutorial doing just that.

Comment: Yes I did check that. The problem in that code is they called the `SetDesktopWallpaper(Args[0])` from the `Main` function. But I need to call it on the `MainWindow_Closed` event. but I can't figure out a way to pass the value of `Args[0]`